# Why isn't no order (as opposed to ASC vs DESC) allowed for Mongo indexes?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-indexes

I assume other DBs behave the same way -

```
{
    Collection: db.Collection(VibeChatUser),
    Index: &mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys: bson.M{
            "Email": 1, // specify the field name and order (1 for ascending, -1 for descending)
        },
        Options: options.Index().SetUnique(true), // additional index options like uniqueness
    },
},
```

here I create an index on the email field - however it really doesn't matter what order they appear? Or maybe it does if binary search is used - not sure.

I am just surprised their isn't an index that allows for zero (unordered) - like so:

```
        Keys: bson.M{
            "Email": 0, // zero for unordered - this isn't real
        },
```

I don't know enough about indexes to understand this for sure - anyone know why an unordered index wouldn't be an option?

Comment: I suppose it's just a design decision.  If their keys are implemented via a hash, then you wouldn't need ordering.  If their keys are implemented by, say, binary search, then ordering would be important.

Comment: why binary search vs a hash, and also why not both?

Comment: From the [offcial doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/), *The ordering of the index entries supports efficient equality matches and range-based query operations.*

Comment: As I said, it's a design decision.  I don't think a database designer would ever do both; the gain isn't worth the cost in terms of space.  Most SQL engines use a hash, because SQL rows aren't ordered.  Mongo rows are ordered, so a binary search makes more sense.